# Modular reduction on ideals generated by two elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, ideals

I know that $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is a commutative ring with unity and for any two elements $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, the set

$\langle f(x), g(x)\rangle  = \{ \alpha(x)f(x) + \beta(x)g(x) : \alpha(x) \land \beta(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x] \}$

is the ideal generated by $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.

I am trying to visualize what the elements of $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{ \langle f(x), g(x)\rangle }$ looks like, but I don't know how to do modular reduction in this case.

When we are working with with ideal generated by a single element, for instance, $f(x)$, then I know that two elements $p(x) + \langle f(x)\rangle $ and $q(x) + \langle f(x)\rangle $ are equal in $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{\langle f(x)\rangle }$ if

$p(x) \equiv q(x) (\mod f(x))$

So, how can I do the same for elements of  $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{ \langle f(x), g(x)\rangle }$ ?

In order to find a polynomial $q(x)$ such that

$p(x) \equiv q(x) (\mod \langle f(x), g(x)\rangle )$

do I have to calculate $p(x) \mod (f(x) + q(x))$ or $(p(x) \mod f(x)) \mod q(x)$ or something else ?

*--- EDIT ----*

For instance, in the section 2.1 of [this paper](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-16295-9_3), the authors define $R_{x-a}$ as $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{ \langle x^n + 1, x - a\rangle }$, for $a \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then, they present exactly the following sentence:

> For $f(x) + \langle x^n + 1, x - a\rangle \in R_{x-a}$, we denote by $[f(x)]_{R_{x-a}} \in \mathbb{Z}$ the unique integer with $[f(x)]_{R_{x-a}} \equiv f(x) (\mod x^n + 1, x - a)$, and $[f(x)]_{R_{x-a}} \in \{0,...,|a^n+1|-1\}$.

So, in this case, any polynomial $f(x)$ is reduced to a zero-degree polynomial $[f(x)]_{R_{x-a}}$ (this is why they say that it belongs to $\mathbb{Z}$).

But how to find this $[f(x)]_{R_{x-a}}$ for any given $f(x)$ ?

Comment: Vitor, to check whether $p$ and $q$ are congruent modulo $(f,g)$, what you really want to know is whether $q - p$ belongs to the ideal $(f,g)$. So what you need is a method to test a polynomial for membership in that ideal.

Comment: @David Do you know such a method? For polynomials over a field we have Grobner bases, but in $\mathbb Z[X]$...?

Comment: @user26857 I haven't studied any methods like that, but I understand that they exist. See this paper, which discusses an algorithm in the case of several variables: https://www.math.ucla.edu/~matthias/pdf/ideal2.pdf I think it's likely that, in the case of a single variable and just two generators, something relatively simple is possible, but I don't know what that would be.

Comment: There are algorithms for computing Gröbner bases in polynomial rings over $\mathbb{Z}$ (cf. [this article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0747717188800208), for instance), but I'm not familiar with them.